# Is it possible to reduce the image size by decodeWidth and decodeHeight properties

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to save images taken from camera online. But the image size is more than a MB.

I came across decodeWidth and decodeHeight properties, but didn't get how it works. Is it possible to reduce the size of Image taken from these properties.

```
<StackLayout>
    <Image src="" decodeWidth="400" decodeHeight="400" loadMode="async" />
    <Label text="With loadMode set to async the UI won't be blocked" 
     textWrap="true" />
</StackLayout>
```

I need to reduce the size of the image to 50px or less before uploading. How to achieve this.

i tried something like this but i'm getting image not saved.

```
 let ImageAsset = require('tns-core-modules/image-asset').ImageAsset;

  const asset = new ImageAsset("~/images/nature.jpg");
  asset.options = {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    keepAspectRatio: true
  };
  console.log(asset);

  const imageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");
  const fileSystemModule = require("tns-core-modules/file-system");
  const img = imageSourceModule.fromFile(asset._android);
  const folderRoot = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.documents();
  folderRoot._path = "/storage/emulated/0/";
  const folder = folderRoot.getFolder("AAAA/");
  const pathDest = fileSystemModule.path.join(folder._path, `sample.jpg`);

  const exists = fileSystemModule.File.exists(pathDest);

  if (exists == true) {
    const saved = img.saveToFile(pathDest, "jpg");
    if (saved) {
      console.log("Image saved successfully!");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Image not saved successfully!");
  }
```

```
console 

JS: {
JS:   "_observers": {},
JS:   "_options": {
JS:     "width": 100,
JS:     "height": 100,
JS:     "keepAspectRatio": true
JS:   },
JS:   "_android": "/data/data/org.nativescript.cameraplus/files/app/images/nature.jpg"
JS: }
JS: Image not saved successfully!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decodeWidth` / `decodeHeight` helps to load a lower resolution image on `Image` component.

To get the resized image, you could do something like

```
import { ImageAsset } from 'tns-core-modules/image-asset';

const asset = new ImageAsset(path);
asset.options = {
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  keepAspectRatio: true
};
```

You could call `getImageAsync()` on the image asset to get the resized native image data Or simply save it to a file and upload.

**Update:**

To save the image, use image source module as follows

```
imageSourceModule.fromAsset(asset)
 .then(img => img.saveToFile(pathDest, "jpg"));
```

Comment: i tried the above answer but i'm not getting image saved. i have edited the question itself what i have tried. please correct it if you find any mistake.

Comment: this was working fine, is their any way to improve the clarity of the image and reduce the size to 50px. right now 1.21MB image got reduced to 22.95KB for W 100 and  H 100, can i give width and height in pixels, will it affect on different screen devices.

Comment: can you please clarify what is 100 here. whether it's in Pixel or something else. the reduced image size is same in all device right..!

Comment: Yes those are pixels.

Comment: i'm asking too much, this is the last one. how w 100Px and h 100Px convert into KB. if you don't mind please.